# Items on sliding menu(jfeinstein) uncliclable

Tags: android, slidingmenu, jfeinstein

i am doing sliding menu. Everything works well but items on sliding menu not clickable.Here is my code.
    package kz.redone.labs.hook;

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
private SlidingMenu sm;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initSlidingMenu();
}


private void initSlidingMenu(){
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
   //       sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset); 

    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    sm.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);





}
```

}
here the MenuActivity

```
  public class MenuActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
private ListView lvMenu;
private SimpleAdapter sa;
private ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> data;
TextView  tvMain;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle              savedInstanceState) { 

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_menu, container, false);
}

public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    tvMain = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMain);
    tvMain.setOnClickListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stubmsg
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.tvMain:
        Log.d("tag", "message");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Main", 1500).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
 }
```

and here is activity_menu.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Main"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvSetting"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvMain"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="Settings"/>



 </RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml cosists only of textview.
Thanks!

Comment: Try setting the onClickListeners programmatically via setOnClickListener(this) as that will call set its clickable to true as well.

Comment: Did not get what u say ? Could u explain more or show some examples.